# About golang array

Tags: go

```
a := [...]int{5, 4: 1, 0, 2: 3, 2, 1: 4 }
fmt.Println(a)
```

the result is [5 4 3 2 1 0].
How it's sort?

```
a := [...]int{5, 4: 1, 0, 2: 3, 2, 1: 4 ,12,11,10}
fmt.Println(a)
```

the result is

```
prog.go:8: duplicate index in array literal: 2
prog.go:8: duplicate index in array literal: 3
prog.go:8: duplicate index in array literal: 4
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

Who can explain the both result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw Dave Cheney tweet this the other day.
My understanding is this:

#### First one - Dave's working one

The `<number_here>:` is an index in the array. This "sets" the current index.. which is why further into the declaration the index must be "reset" back in the array. So, the first number is `5` (index 0), the second "entry" has an index of `4:` .. so the value `1` will be at index 4:

```
5 _ _ _ 1 _
         ^ index is currently here
```

..the next one has no index but it will continue after the last index given. which is `4+1` .. so index `5` gets the value `0`:

```
5 _ _ _ 1 0
           ^ index is here.. it needs to be reset
```

Now the index will overrun .. so its gets set further back. The next one is `2:` .. so that puts the value below with the value `3`:

```
5 _ 3 _ 1 0
     ^ index is here
```

Next one again, continues on, since it has no index:

```
5 _ 3 2 1 0
       ^ index is here
```

Then the last one has index `1:` .. with the value 4:

```
5 4 3 2 1 0
```

#### Second one - your broken one.

The second one is the same thing - but you haven't protected the over-writing of a currently placed index. Lets step through it:

Value `5` at index 0:

```
5 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
 ^ index is here
```

Value `1` at index 4:

```
5 _ _ _ 1 _ _ _ _
         ^ index is here
```

Value `0` at index 5 (remember, it continues on):

```
5 _ _ _ 1 0 _ _ _
           ^ index is here
```

Value `3` at index 2:

```
5 _ 3 _ 1 0 _ _ _
     ^ index is here
```

Value `2` at index 3 (again, it continues on:

```
5 _ 3 2 1 0 _ _ _
       ^ index is here
```

Value `4` at index 1:

```
5 4 3 2 1 0 _ _ _
   ^ index is here ... you're awfully close to overwriting the next value
```

Value `12` at index 2:

```
5 4 12 2 1 0 _ _ _
    ^^^^^ BOOOM
```

## Boom..

..you've overwritten the value 3 and will continue to do so given where the index is for the remaining values. This is the problem..

Comment: Now the index will overrun .. so its gets set further back. The next one is 2: .. so that puts the value below with the value 3:                      Why the next one is 2: when its gets set further back?

Comment: 2 is lower than the last index - which was 5. If it was allowed to keep going it would go past the end of the array and more space would be allocated.

Comment: ...and thus, the example/trivia would have a gap in the output.

Comment: thank you. I got it. The value 12 assign to index 2: after value 4 assign to index 1:. It has a confict.

Comment: Wow, had no idea about indices in array literals. Wild.